# Extract XML tag from text file

Tags: java, xml, text, extract

my intention is to extract single or nested XML tags from a text file. My input file structure is both plain text and XML (in my case HTML) format. What i want to do is to scan input discarding everything until an XML tag is reached; then extract it all (with everything nested in) and continue this way until the whole file is processed.
Before attempting doing it on my own, i'd like to see if there is some java library i don't know which could help me.

Thank you all.

Comment: Perhaps, http://jsoup.org might be able to do this...?

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the XML file and create a it's relative DOM tree. Check out here [Java XML-DOM parser tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/31/java-xml-dom-parser-example-tutorial/)